# ec2 setting up MX record not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, mx-record, google

I am trying to set up google business emails for my site and I am having trouble creating the MX records to work.  I have added all 5 records and they have not registered.  This was add a couple of days ago and from what I have read, amazon doesn't take more than 24 hours... so i am out of ideas.  Any help or point in the right direction would help.  Thank you.

Here is what google requested
[image]

Here are my record sets
[image]

Here are the results of my records:
http://www.intodns.com/bracketfanatic.com

Here is what google responds with
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've set the `Name` field correctly.  Google's reference to a Name/Host/Alias of `@` is a BIND shorthand for "*the zone itself*", and since you're not using BIND, that doesn't really apply.  If you try setting the MX record for just `bracketfanatic.com`, rather than `@.bracketfanatic.com`, things should work somewhat better.

**Edit**: I think you'll find things are better now:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig mx bracketfanatic.com @ns-21.awsdns-02.com.
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
bracketfanatic.com.     3600    IN      MX      1 aspmx.l.google.com.
bracketfanatic.com.     3600    IN      MX      10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
bracketfanatic.com.     3600    IN      MX      10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
bracketfanatic.com.     3600    IN      MX      5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
bracketfanatic.com.     3600    IN      MX      5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just updated it, and i'll give it a couple of hours and try again.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well it didn't take a couple of hours to work.  Thank you for your help.